# One profile on multiple domains

Tags: authentication, next.js, backend, system-design

I'm planning to build a link-in-bio type of service, let's say I have 3 domains:

**1. main-domain.com**

**2. second-domain.com**

**3. third-domain.com**

When user registered an account at **main-domain.com**, the user will get a public page at **main-domain.com/usernameX**

Now I like to have it automatically available on other 2 domains with same username:

**second-domain.com/usernameX**

and

**third-domain.com/usernameX**

Is it possible to use micro service to make it happen automatically or I need to have 3 separate backends access the same DB?

Or how would you implement it? If you had experience in project like this or similar please give me some suggestions!

Hope the question is clear enough, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider a user authentication framework like [nextjs-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0) for achieving centralized authentication across all three domains in your scenario.
Auth0 supports "[Universal Login](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/auth0-universal-login)", where authentication is performed once at a centralized domain and the authenticated state can be shared across multiple domains.
Plus, With Auth0, you benefit from added security features like multi-factor authentication, rate limiting, and anomaly detection.

A high-level overview of how it could work would be:

- A user registers or logs in via Auth0 on `main-domain.com`.
- Auth0 would act as the centralized authentication domain. When a user tries to access `second-domain.com` or `third-domain.com`, they would be redirected to Auth0 for authentication.
- Upon successful authentication, Auth0 will issue JWT tokens which can be validated across all your domains.
- Use the tokens to fetch and display the correct user profile information from your shared database, making the user profile accessible as `main-domain.com/usernameX`, `second-domain.com/usernameX`, and `third-domain.com/usernameX`.

You can use a single backend with domain routing (using [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) or [NGiNX](https://www.nginx.com/)), and shared business logic.
Or you can use separate backends ([microservices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/microservices)), but they would still access the same database. An API gateway could be used to route requests to the appropriate backend.

But in both cases Auth0 will serve as your centralized authentication service, issuing tokens that can be validated by whichever backend handles the request. A single backend or multiple backends would verify the JWT tokens issued by Auth0 to ensure that the user is authenticated and authorized.

Comment: I appreciate your detail answer! It's much more clear to me how I should implement it now. I forgot to mention that user will just need to register their new account at the main site only, the second and third domain only to show the user public profile (data from the same database), when user need to modify some info they will need to do it at the main site domain, Vercel domain routing with single backend seems the simplest option

Comment: @Huy That should work indeed!